# Validation inputs

Tags: javascript, php

I want to validate the username as a number only (php or javascript). The validation I did accepts numbers with digits.
Also I want to validate the phone number input as `+961-00/000 000` (2digits/6digits) (php or javascript)

This is my php code:

```
function validate_username($field) {
    if (preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/",$field))
       return "Only numbers";
       return "";
}


  <th>
    Id: 
</th> 
<td> 
    <input type="text" name="username" required="" 
 placeholder="ID"/>

        <?php if ($_SESSION['user_exists'] !== "ok") 
        echo "<div style='color:red;'>ID Already 
       exists</div>"; 
        echo "<div style='color:red;'>$userv</div>" ?>
    </div>
</td>

<th>
    Phone number:
</th> 
<td> 
    <input type="text" name="phonenumber" required="" 
 placeholder="+961 --/--- ---"/>
</td>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working here ?

Comment: For phone number validation, you can use this: https://regex101.com/r/wQ2mF4/1 (you have code generator button there, too, very nice regex101 feature)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is doing it from server-side (javascript can be modified by user).

You tried with is_numeric?

```
$tel = "hello world";
if(!is_numeric($tel)) {
    echo "$tel isn't numeric";
}
```

[PHP is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-numeric.php)